# Ionic routing question about tabs vs pages

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to learn ionic and SQLite, I am new.
Is this (https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/) up to date to use it on Ionic 5.4.16? If no then what should I watch out for?

Also on this tutorial it shows how to do it with pages, but I want to do it with tabs. Can I still follow the routing tutorial on this or do I need to add the routing part to tabs-routing.module.ts instead of app-routing.module.ts? I have been trying to figure it out, but I find my self stuck.

And when I use tabs then I can just rename home and song to tab3 and tab4 if I want to and just route it there?

```
// app-routing.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
  {
    path: 'song/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./song/song.module').then( m => m.SongPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You can place your routes in `tabs-routing.module.ts`. Note that you will have to prefix `/tabs` to your routes like this example `this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home')`

Comment: So when I am dealing with tabs, I add those to `tabs-routing.module.ts` not `app-routing.module.ts` correct?
And if my tab name is tab4 then instead of:

`{ path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},`


I do:   
`{ path: 'tab4', loadChildren: () => import('./tab4/tab4.module').then( m => m.Tab4PageModule)},`

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: First question: yes. Every route you place in `tabs-routing` will come behind the original `/tabs`. You will find this at the top of the routing schema. This means that every page described in `tabs-routing` will show the tabbar + page. If your route is in `app-routing`, your tabbar will not be shown. Second: you can use your normal routes like your `home` example. What I mean is that you have to call the `/tabs/` before every call to the home page for example. Otherwise it will look in `app-routing` instead of `tab-routing`